# Flow: combine exact object types

Tags: javascript, flowtype

I have two types, one extends another using object type spread and adds an optional property `AccountPayload` and `Route` in my case.

It's not clear to me why I can't use an object of `AccountPayload` type when `Route` expected.

```
// @flow

export type AccountPayload = {|
  +organisationId: string,
  +userIndex: number
|};

type Route = {|
  ...AccountPayload, 
  +chatUuid?: string
|};

const payload: AccountPayload = {
  organisationId: '*',
  userIndex: 1
};

const routeF: Route = payload;      // error
const routeS: Route = {...payload}; // ok
```

[Try flow here](https://flow.org/try/#0KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcCCBjDECuA7GABQENEAbCYgEzgF44BvAHwCg44BqaAc2LwEsAzsRj8IeAJJUAXHEEwo-PNwA0bTjkHAoEvFVCy8OALYAjbSyYBfANwsWSFHABKuGKnrN1AOl+Zs+ESkFNQqcOocGAAWIgCqOPxUAPyy8orKlrb22HjycGDBlDLoWLgEJORFdIzqPHxCImKSxQDkAFQtauya2rr6ILIAjCxZLDl5UG7Asq447tUFldQ2QA)

Comment: I believe that this is a bug, that will be fixed by this PR https://github.com/facebook/flow/pull/7298